# How can I get my Application to render the application template before my routes are done loading?

Tags: ember.js

I want there to be a loading spinner shown while my routes are loading but unfortunately none of my templates render until whatever route I'm in is done loading?.

Answer (score 0):

Ember has a built loading route at each resource level (including the root of the app).  If you have a long last request at the application route it will block the highest available loading route. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

> If a route with the path `foo.bar.baz` returns a promise that doesn't immediately resolve, Ember will try to find a loading route in the hierarchy above `foo.bar.baz` that it can transition into, starting with `foo.bar.baz's` sibling:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/716/edit

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this was implemented in Ember V1.0 which is what I am using (can't upgrade due to huge codebase).

Comment: In that case you'll need to define it each time you are transitioning (where you care about it)... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/716/edit

Comment: Can't do that if they go to a URL directly which is the case I am trying to solve :\. I had to set my model in setupController and I had to make all nested resources check if the model for the parent resource is loaded yet if not they register a listener.